# R Shiny: fast reactive image display

Tags: r, image, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm trying to display images in my shiny app reactively. I've successfully done that in the **server.R** script with:

```
output$display.image <- renderImage({

    image_file <- paste("www/",input$image.type,".jpeg",sep="")

    return(list(
      src = image_file,
      filetype = "image/jpeg",
      height = 520,
      width = 696
    ))

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
```

BUT it's **very slow**.

However, it is **VERY fast** to embed one of the images into the **ui.R** script like so:

```
tabPanel("Live Images", img(src = "img_type1.jpeg"))
```

Why is there such a difference? Is there any way to make the reactive images appear faster?

Comment: When you send the image URL from the reactive, you are doing a transfer from the server to the client via JavaScript. This data needs to be unpacked by the client and used to transform the document, which all takes time. What are your requirements? Does the image need to be loaded dynamically? Is there a finite set of images that might be loaded?

Comment: @sdgfsdh The image needs to be loaded dynamically based on the user input (input$image.type), and yes there is a finite set of images that may be loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can use `conditionalPanel` to do this, it embed all your images but only the one which have `TRUE` to the condition will be displayed :

```
tabPanel("Live Images", 
     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.image_type == 'img_type1'",
                      img(src = "img_type1.jpeg")
     ),
     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.image_type == 'img_type2'",
                      img(src = "img_type2.jpeg")
     )
)
```

And change the name of your input from `image.type` to `image_type` because `.` have special meaning in Javascript (as between `input` and `image_type`).

If you have a lot of images, you can always do something like that :

```
tabPanel("Live Images", 
         lapply(X = seq_len(10), FUN = function(i) {
           conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.image_type == 'img_type", i, "'"),
                            img(src = paste0("img_type", i, ".jpeg"))
           )
         })
)
```

For example, with images from this [post](http://playingwithr.blogspot.fr/2011/06/animated-plots-with-r.html) by [tsperry](https://www.blogger.com/profile/10132404464368054705) (you can find it on rbloggers too), you can do :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Live Images", 
         # 50 images to display
         lapply(X = seq_len(50), FUN = function(i) {
           # condition on the slider value
           conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.slider == ", i),
                            # images are on github
                            img(src = paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pvictor/images/master/",
                                             sprintf("%04d", i), "plot.png"))
           )
         }),
         sliderInput(inputId = "slider", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 50, value = 1, 
                     animate = animationOptions(interval = 100, loop = TRUE))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```